# Reading Nfc tags on Jsp page?

Tags: java, jsp, nfc, acr122

```
    <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
        pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <title>Insert title here</title>
    </head>
    <body>




<input type="text" name="a" />

<input type="submit" value="READ" >

<% 


%>
</body>
</html>
```

This is my code and i want to read nfc tag on read button click. I have ACR122U device and NFC cards + SDK . But i am not sure how to use sdk with my JSP web application. Can you please help me out to resolve my problem.

Comment: This will not work because there is no connection between web and the nfc hardware. Unless you install some kind of plugin and I doubt there is one. Perhaps an applet might be able to do this but this would create the necessity of Java on the client.

Comment: Can you please help me to do this. I want to read nfc tags on my JSP page.

Comment: Sorry, but this is technically not doable. At least not with all browsers:  You could read at the Server but not the client

Comment: Someone has given me idea of using an GO TO TAG application. read tags there and send UID to notefile and than code on jsp to read the textfilr. IS this worthful ?

Comment: How do you want to connect notefile and jsp ? Draw a picture and add it to your question